# Facebook fan page - search keywords

Tags: facebook, search, facebook-pages, keyword

Apparently Facebook doesn't allow you to [change the name of a fan page with more than 100 fans](http://www.facebook.com/help/search/?q=change%20name)

This is causing problems for one of my clients, as they've recently gone through this whole rebranding phase which basically means they're now known under a different name.

Now they want to show up in Facebook's autocomplete search results for this new name, but as far as I can tell Facebook are basing these results on the fan page name — and nothing else.

Is there no other way to make Facebook pages recognize search keywords outside of the fan page name?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the help section, you need to provide insight for Facebook to understand your problem under their feedback form: [Page Name Change Feedback](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=271607792873806)